# Hide statusbar / toolbar / menubar in TinyMCE4

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, django-tinymce

i am using multiple TinyMCE4 - Editors on the same page and would like to hide the bars ( statusbar / toolbar / menubar ) of the editors when the user is not working in it. But they have to be shown when the user is working in an editor.

Any ideas how i could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using TinyMCE's inline mode?

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/inline/

The toolbar only appears when you click into the editable section and disappears once you click outside of the editable section.  This sounds like it would meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks! Thats perfect